# How to TeX a table contain large bracket

Tags: tables, arrows

How to Tex a table in the form? I'm not interested in the detail of the matrix content, just interested in the form of the matrix, especially how to put the arrows and labels outside the matrix.

[image]

Here is what I got so far:

```
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c|c|ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \gets & \ket{1}\\
\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \gets & \ket{1}\\
\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \gets & \ket{1}\\
\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \gets & \ket{1}\\
\uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow & & \\
\ket{1} & \ket{1} & \ket{1} & \ket{1} & & 
\end{array}
\right)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste  the table content? It's really not so fun to make an example from scratch just to try out things. And there are some duplicates on this site too.

Comment: Would putting an `array` around it help? You might need `\multicolumn` to put the matrix in.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @percusse thanks for the suggestion, I've put the content. I'm very new to tex and this site, could you suggest some terms for me to search for the duplicates? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proof-of-concept using the [`blkarray` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,blkarray}
\begin{document}
$\begin{blockarray}{(cccc)>{\leftarrow}l}
  a & b & c & d & 1 \\
  e & f & g & h & 2 \\
  i & j & k & l & 3 \\
  \begin{block}{ccccl}
    \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow & \\
    4 & 5 & 6 & 7
  \end{block}
\end{blockarray}$
\end{document}
```

The idea is to define an "overlay" `blockarray` environment that contains the desired encompassing structure. Elements within that differ from this is constructed using the `block` environment. The interface is similar to that of `tabular` and `array` structures, with the benefit of being able to use [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) functionality (as I've done with the right-most column's `\leftarrow` insertion).

<sub>Any question should be directed to the package author [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends). He frequently solves problems regarding all his package deficiencies there... for free.</sub>